# CSS3 3D transform, z order is not right

Tags: css, transform

I create two squares with z translate and put in perspective-origin in css.
This is the link to jsbin: https://jsbin.com/bebucum/edit?html,output.

Following is the most relevant CSS:

```
.container {
  -webkit-perspective: 700;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 450px 000px;
}

.square:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
}
.square:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px);
}
```

Most of the output makes sense to me. However there is one part I do not quite understand.

I think the yellow square should be below the blue one, as its translateZ is negative. But the output is the other way around.

Can someone help me understand this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve correct 3d positioning, you need to set

```
transform-style: preserve-3D;
```

I have also removed webkit prefixes, they aren't necesary now.

```css
.container {
  perspective: 700px;
  perspective-origin: 450px 0px;
  transform-style: preserve-3D;
}

.square {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.square:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.square:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
  transform: translateZ(-200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">
  </div>
  <div class="square">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @vals! I added the perserve-3D. However, as you can see in the  jsbin link which I have it updated, the yellow square is still above the below. Is there anything I am still missing?

Comment: I see I can take out the Google prefix for the transform. But that does not apply for perspective. Maybe that is because my chrome is outdate?

Comment: You need to set px on the perspective for it to work in modern browsers. See the snippet

Comment: Happy that it helped